# Browserify - Exposing A Method on the Client Side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browserify

I guess I'm missing something with Browserify. I want to browserify my custom node module, which exposes a couple of functions. How would I do that?

Every example I've seen in browserify it's always a console.log or an alert. It's not good to me if it runs immediately. I want to run my browserify code on demand.

But for the sake of this example. Say I export a sum method. Take this example:

```
module.exports = {
  sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
};
```

After I browserify this via the standard command: browserify index.js -o bundle.js.

Then I add this file to the my index.html.

Within my AngularJS application or any client side code. How do I access this **sum** method?

I can't find it on window.sum. Or maybe I got it all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

@WellDone2044 answers should give you the idea how to solve your problem. When you run browserify as shown by WellDone2044, it will bundle your javascript files base on your main file which in the example is `index.js`. The bundled output will be written to `bundle.js` and browserify will include Node's `require` function. Therefore, you'll be able to use the `require` method on your client side scripts. Note that you must always run browserify on each modification you made to your js scripts. You're index file might look like this:

```js
var sum = require('./sum.js');

console.log(sum(1,2)); // displays 3
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get really the problem but i try to explain how i use browserify

```
//sum.js
var sum = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
module.exports = sum


//index.js
var sum = require('./sum.js');
console.log(sum(1,2)); //print 3
```

now i execute browserify index.js -o bundle.js

Comment: The problem is I want to create a function on in node.js that I can expose and use in my client side code. Can I use require on the client side?

Comment: if you are writing code on server side that will run on node.js you don't need browserify because node.js can understand require. 
Client side you can use require (so you can install module with npm and require it or include your own module) but you need browserify to put everything together and create a unique file.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it on `window.sum` because that is exactly the point -- you don't want global variables. So as already mentioned you use `module.exports = something` to export your module so you can use it in other files without using globals. Inside of another file you call `var obj = require('path/to/file/with/module.exports');`. When you run this through browserify it will bundle everything together along with a `require` function. The `require` function knows how to find the object you exported. So basically doing `var obj = require('./sum.js')` will give you the object you exported, and you can call the sum as `obj.sum()`.

Comment: Sounds good and thank you. Are you saying I can call `var obj = require('./sum.js')` in my client side code and I will be able to run sum() and that object?

Comment: How about standalone mode? Apparently that moves it to the the window object. I know that's not ideal, but I guess that's a way of doing it.

Comment: If you exposed your module as an object, e.g. module.exports = {sum: ...}, then yes you can use obj.sum(). I'm not sure about standalone, haven't used it.